# What is the purpose of the vampires' pink fog?

Tags: wynonna-earp

In Season 3, Episode 1 of *Wynnona Earp*, there are some vampires that conspicuously employ a pink fog. I can't quite figure out what the fog is for, though. It's not the vampires themselves in an incorporeal form as one might imagine from traditional vampire lore, since all the scenes suggest that the vampires are physically standing around in the fog. As a means of concealment, it's not all that great, since it's conspicuous and relies on the target walking into the fog. And it's evident that they're not constantly producing it, since we see them without it several times, so it's not something involuntary. They don't use it to control the minds of their victims, since they appear to need touch for that, and walking into the fog doesn't result in being glamored,  yet it seems important to them to have it around in large quantities at the party where they plan to kill members of the original families, despite it not even being thick  enough to obscure vision there.

So what purpose does the fog serve? Does it let them maintain their control once established in some sense? Do they just like the aesthetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my memory of the episode, it only appears to be used in a manner that's not purely for atmosphere in two situations. The first is when Doc is attacked and abducted from his bar, and the second is when Wynonna enters the barn on the homestead. In both cases, the purpose of the fog is to conceal the vampire, allowing them to attack and/or glamour an otherwise dangerous target with minimal risk; they're able to place a trap or even get within touching distance without being seen at all.

The vampires don't seem to be particularly skilled at combat (they're trivially killed at the end of the episode), instead relying on deception, stealth and their ability to glamour victims.

As you said in your question, in other situations where the fog is present there doesn't *appear* to be a purpose for it, so it could just be that they like the look.